# "Follow user" database table design

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I'm trying to determine the best table design for a "follow/unfollow user" feature, similar to Twitter **(edit:** I'm not making a Twitter-like application.) Below is my the current table design and php handling. I'm not certain if it's the best approach and would really appreciate your feedback.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_follow` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `follower` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `following` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `subscribed` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `follow_unique` (`follower`,`following`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=76 ;
```

On follow, the followers id is added to the `follower` field and the id of the user that will be followed is added to `following`. I'm also recording the date a user subscribed to follow another user in the `subscribed` field. The date of subscription might be used for sorting.

When a user unfollows, I simply delete the respective row.

In order to prevent duplicate rows I made columns `follower` and `following` unique. If a user is already following an id and clicks to follow again, I get database error 1062. For instance

> Duplicate entry '62-88' for key 'follow_unique'

Obviously when already following a user, the follower sees a `unfollow` button. This is achieved by checking if a follower-following table row exists between 2 users. If `rows > 0` I display `unfollow` otherwise `follow`.

Well, what do you think?

Comment: I'm not trying to recreate Twitter.. Its for a totally different purpose but has the same functionality as Twitter in terms of subscriptions

Comment: It sounds good, but I would add (if you haven't already) Foreign Keys constraints on `follower` and `following` to your Users table.

Comment: What you're doing looks fine to me.  I would suggest using `ENGINE=InnoDB` rather than `MyISAM` though, so you can enforce `FOREIGN KEY` relationships and `ON DELETE/UPDATE`.  This is likely to require engine changes to many of your tables to be effective though.

Comment: @Dirk: MyISAM has no foreign keys.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it's a very good design, and should meet your needs nicely.  One thing; you should probably make the `follower` and `following` foreign keys.  Oh, and for simplicity sake, I'd make the `subscribed` column `TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` just to capture the datetime the user subscribed.

Comment: Thanks! By Foreign Keys constraints you mean unique ids for follower and following right? If so they are.

Comment: @CyberJunkie by foreign key constraints, they mean switch your tables to the alternative mysql table engine, innodb, which allows for foreign keys. these constraints make it so that for instance if you were to delete a user record, and there were records in other tables connected by foreign key, those records would also be deleted, thus preventing orphaned records. also works for updates. can be set up in phpMyAdmin. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I was not aware of this feature, I will definitely look more into it!

Comment: In addition, FKs prevent INSERTing into the following table users that are not in your users table.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you make follower and following together the primary key. There is no need for a seperate `id` field.

Comment: I have been advised this before but for some reason it seems "hacky" to me, also I'm not able to make both primary. I get an error or nothing happens. Moreover I want a A.I. unique primary key. It's database standard. I don't mean to sound dismissive, I just don;t know a lot about this approach