# What's the best way to store who a user is following for a social network?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a social network right now, and I was wondering: to store which users are following who, should I make another table called "Following" with rows of who is following who, or add a Following column in my users table and store all the user IDs they are following as an array?

Comment: `store all the user IDs they are following as an array` is usually a sign of bad database design.

Comment: Please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6653704/follow-user-database-table-design

Comment: Never, never, never, never store multiple values in a single column! Never! N-E-V-E-R!

Comment: Look into relationships.  Specifically "Many to Many".  You're most likely going to want to use a join table for something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better option will be to use a separate table to implement a many to many relationship
OR
Since you're working on a social network, consider using any of the NOSQL alternatives, this are the kind of instances where they shine. Read up on them and you can decide if any suits your app better than traditional RDBMS